# Getting settingwithcopywarning error even after using .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\rt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:337: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
C:\Users\rt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:517: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

However, I am already using .loc already so not sure why this error is occuring. The code outline is like this:

```
for name, group in results.groupby():
    for idx, row in group.iterrows():
        group.loc[idx, 'area'] = 10.0
```

I am using latest pandas (0.20.3) and python (3.6)

Comment: Can you add the results df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that you are modifying a *copy* of the dataframe you may be intending to modify, instead of the dataframe itself. In this case, `group` is actually another dataframe created by the `.groupby()` generator.

Your code is leaving `results` untouched, and modifying `group` instead. This is probably not what you intend to do, which is why the warning comes up. If it is, and you want to disable the warning, you can do `pd.set_option('SettingWithCopyWarning', None)`.

Comment: I do intend to modify and use `group` so that should be ok then :) thanks!